# Is it possible to convert the complex SQL into rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## SPEC

I need to pick all rooms that don't have a single day with `saleable = FALSE` in the requested time period`(07-09 ~ 07-19)`:

I have a table room with 1 row per room.

I have a table room_skus with one row per room and day (complete set for the relevant time range).

The column saleable is boolean NOT NULL and date is defined date NOT NULL

```
SELECT id
FROM   room r
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   room_skus
   WHERE  date BETWEEN '2016-07-09' AND '2016-07-19'
   AND    room_id = r.id
   AND    NOT saleable
   GROUP  BY 1
   );
```

The above SQL query is working, but I wonder how could I translate it into Rails ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have array of room_ids called `room_ids`:

`needed_room_ids = room_ids - RoomSku.where(room_id: room_ids, date: '2016-07-09'..'2016-07-19', sealable: false).pluck(:room_id)`

If your model of `room_sku` is called `RoomSku`

Updated version:

`room_ids = Room.all.select { |record| record.room_skus.present? }.map(&:id)`

And then:

`needed_room_ids = room_ids - RoomSku.where(room_id: room_ids, date: '2016-07-09'..'2016-07-19', sealable: false).pluck(:room_id)`

It won't be one query, but you avoid plain SQL like this.

Comment: Thanks for your repla, it really helps a lot

But I think it will be a problem,

That is, what is a room which doesn't have any RoomSku record on `2016-07-12`

The aforementioned room should be removed from the result as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any project here to test something like it, but it should work:

```
Room.where.not(id: RoomSku.where(date: DateTime.parse('2016-07-09').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")..DateTime.parse('2016-07-19').strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), saleable: false).pluck(:room_id))
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your repla, it really helps a lot

But I think it will be a problem,

That is, what is a room which doesn't have any RoomSku record on `2016-07-12`

The aforementioned room should be removed from the result as well.

Comment: Can you past here the exactly query generated by my answer?